# Find all subsequences of given string

Tags: c#, regex, subsequence

I have a string (which does not contain a newline character) and I want to find all subsequences of another string that are in the first one.

For example, let's assume that the string that I am looking for is `"hello world"`. If I search (using a Regex) for it in this string: `"1h2e3l4l5o6 7w8o9r0l0d0"`, it should be able to find out that it does contain (once) the string `"hello world"`. It should also be able to find multiple matches in the following string: `"hheelloo  wwoorrlldd"`.

I have the following code:

```
string stringToSearch = // could be anything (no newline)
int numOfSubSeq = 0;
Regex myRegex = new Regex("h.*e.*l.*l.*o.* .*w.*o.*r.*l.*d");
MatchCollection matches = myRegex.Matches(stringToSearch);
numOfSubSeq = matches.Count; // I only need the number of matches
```

This works. Sort of. If `stringToSearch` is `"1h2e3l4l5o6 7w8o9r0l0d0"`, it works just fine. But, if `stringToSearch` is `"hheelloo  wwoorrlldd"`, then this Regex can find only one match, which is wrong.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: Sorry. I just added a tag. C#

Comment: Regex will not match overlapping matches, so if you match `aa` against `aaa` you only get one match. Same in your example.

Comment: BTW, how many matches would you expect for `hheelloo  wwoorrlldd`? Two, or 256?

Comment: Just an idea, but if you can use a loop you can either: subtract characters from initial string and loop until no more hits are found, or iterate per character.

Comment: @tobias_k My goal is to find all possible matches.

Comment: "all possible" is not a clear answer. Do you expect each character to be "consumed" once it is used in a match? In this case, one would actually be correct, because there are only two `l` in the `hello` part. Or do you expect every possible combination of characters? Then you'd get 256 matches (first h with first e, first h with second e, and so on)

Comment: The second one. I should be able to get 256 matches.

Comment: Not really a regex problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't have any luck doing this with .NET regexes. Your best bet would be to write an algorithm for it. Regexes aren't the right tool for the job.

That said, you *can* do this with PCRE regexes, and I did just that for fun ;)

> **Disclaimer:** I'm the author of the library I used in this post.

Fisrt, install [PCRE.NET](https://github.com/ltrzesniewski/pcre-net):

```
Install-Package PCRE.NET
```

Then, build a pattern such as this:

```
h.*?e.*?l.*?l.*?o.*?\ .*?w.*?o.*?r.*?l.*?d(?C1)
```

That `(?C1)` thing is called a *callout* in PCRE parlance. It instructs the regex engine to call a custom function of yours at this point of the matching. You can then say if that part should be considered as matching or not.

Count the number of times your callout function is invoked, and tell the engine the pattern should fail, which will force it to backtrack. Job done.

```
public static int GetMatchCount(string searchFor, string searchIn)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchFor) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchIn))
        return 0;

    var patternBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var searchChar in searchFor)
        patternBuilder.Append(Regex.Escape(searchChar.ToString())).Append(".*?");

    patternBuilder.Length -= 3;
    patternBuilder.Append("(?C1)");

    var pattern = new PcreRegex(patternBuilder.ToString());

    var count = 0;
    pattern.Match(searchIn, callout =>
    {
        ++count;
        return PcreCalloutResult.Fail;
    });

    return count;
}
```

Calling `GetMatchCount("hello world", "hheelloo  wwoorrlldd")` returns `512`.

---

Oh, by the way if you'd like to actually see where the characters are located in the input string, here's some code for that:

```
public static void PrintMatches(string searchFor, string searchIn)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchFor) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchIn))
        return;

    var patternBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var searchChar in searchFor)
        patternBuilder.Append("(").Append(Regex.Escape(searchChar.ToString())).Append(").*?");

    patternBuilder.Length -= 3;
    patternBuilder.Append("(?C1)");

    var pattern = new PcreRegex(patternBuilder.ToString());
    var outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    Console.WriteLine(searchIn);
    pattern.Match(searchIn, callout =>
    {
        outputBuilder.Clear();
        outputBuilder.Append(' ', searchIn.Length);

        foreach (var group in callout.Match.Groups.Skip(1))
            outputBuilder[group.Index] = '^';

        Console.WriteLine(outputBuilder);

        return PcreCalloutResult.Fail;
    });
}
```

And here's the result:

```
hheelloo  wwoorrlldd
^ ^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^  ^
^ ^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^  ^^
^ ^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^  ^ ^
^ ^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^  ^^ ^
^ ^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^  ^^  ^
^ ^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^  ^ ^^
^ ^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^  ^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^^ ^ ^  ^^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^^ ^ ^  ^^ ^  ^
^ ^ ^^^ ^ ^  ^^  ^^
^ ^ ^^^ ^ ^  ^^  ^ ^
^ ^ ^^^ ^ ^  ^ ^^ ^
^ ^ ^^^ ^ ^  ^ ^^  ^
^ ^ ^^^ ^ ^  ^ ^ ^^
^ ^ ^^^ ^ ^  ^ ^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^^ ^  ^^ ^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^^ ^  ^^ ^ ^  ^
^ ^ ^^^ ^  ^^ ^  ^^
^ ^ ^^^ ^  ^^ ^  ^ ^
^ ^ ^^^ ^  ^^  ^^ ^
^ ^ ^^^ ^  ^^  ^^  ^
^ ^ ^^^ ^  ^^  ^ ^^
^ ^ ^^^ ^  ^^  ^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^^ ^  ^ ^^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^^ ^  ^ ^^ ^  ^
^ ^ ^^^ ^  ^ ^^  ^^
^ ^ ^^^ ^  ^ ^^  ^ ^
^ ^ ^^^ ^  ^ ^ ^^ ^
^ ^ ^^^ ^  ^ ^ ^^  ^
^ ^ ^^^ ^  ^ ^ ^ ^^
^ ^ ^^^ ^  ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^^  ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^^  ^^ ^ ^ ^  ^
^ ^ ^^^  ^^ ^ ^  ^^
^ ^ ^^^  ^^ ^ ^  ^ ^
^ ^ ^^^  ^^ ^  ^^ ^
^ ^ ^^^  ^^ ^  ^^  ^
^ ^ ^^^  ^^ ^  ^ ^^
^ ^ ^^^  ^^ ^  ^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^^  ^^  ^^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^^  ^^  ^^ ^  ^
^ ^ ^^^  ^^  ^^  ^^
^ ^ ^^^  ^^  ^^  ^ ^
^ ^ ^^^  ^^  ^ ^^ ^
^ ^ ^^^  ^^  ^ ^^  ^
^ ^ ^^^  ^^  ^ ^ ^^
^ ^ ^^^  ^^  ^ ^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^^  ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^^  ^ ^^ ^ ^  ^
^ ^ ^^^  ^ ^^ ^  ^^
^ ^ ^^^  ^ ^^ ^  ^ ^
^ ^ ^^^  ^ ^^  ^^ ^
^ ^ ^^^  ^ ^^  ^^  ^
^ ^ ^^^  ^ ^^  ^ ^^
^ ^ ^^^  ^ ^^  ^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^^  ^ ^ ^^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^^  ^ ^ ^^ ^  ^
^ ^ ^^^  ^ ^ ^^  ^^
^ ^ ^^^  ^ ^ ^^  ^ ^
^ ^ ^^^  ^ ^ ^ ^^ ^
^ ^ ^^^  ^ ^ ^ ^^  ^
^ ^ ^^^  ^ ^ ^ ^ ^^
^ ^ ^^^  ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^  ^
^ ^ ^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^  ^^
^ ^ ^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^  ^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^^ ^ ^  ^^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^^ ^ ^  ^^  ^
^ ^ ^^ ^^ ^ ^  ^ ^^
^ ^ ^^ ^^ ^ ^  ^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^^ ^  ^^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^^ ^  ^^ ^  ^
^ ^ ^^ ^^ ^  ^^  ^^
^ ^ ^^ ^^ ^  ^^  ^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^^ ^  ^ ^^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^^ ^  ^ ^^  ^
^ ^ ^^ ^^ ^  ^ ^ ^^
^ ^ ^^ ^^ ^  ^ ^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^^  ^^ ^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^^  ^^ ^ ^  ^
^ ^ ^^ ^^  ^^ ^  ^^
^ ^ ^^ ^^  ^^ ^  ^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^^  ^^  ^^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^^  ^^  ^^  ^
^ ^ ^^ ^^  ^^  ^ ^^
^ ^ ^^ ^^  ^^  ^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^^  ^ ^^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^^  ^ ^^ ^  ^
^ ^ ^^ ^^  ^ ^^  ^^
^ ^ ^^ ^^  ^ ^^  ^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^^  ^ ^ ^^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^^  ^ ^ ^^  ^
^ ^ ^^ ^^  ^ ^ ^ ^^
^ ^ ^^ ^^  ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^  ^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^^ ^ ^  ^^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^^ ^ ^  ^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^^ ^  ^^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^^ ^  ^^  ^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^^ ^  ^ ^^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^^ ^  ^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^^  ^^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^^  ^^ ^  ^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^^  ^^  ^^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^^  ^^  ^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^^  ^ ^^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^^  ^ ^^  ^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^^  ^ ^ ^^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^^  ^ ^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^^ ^ ^  ^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^^ ^  ^^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^^ ^  ^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^^  ^^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^^  ^^  ^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^^  ^ ^^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^^  ^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^^ ^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^^ ^  ^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^^  ^^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^^  ^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^^ ^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^^  ^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^^
^ ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
^  ^^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
^  ^^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^  ^
^  ^^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^  ^^
^  ^^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^  ^ ^
^  ^^^^ ^ ^ ^  ^^ ^
^  ^^^^ ^ ^ ^  ^^  ^
^  ^^^^ ^ ^ ^  ^ ^^
^  ^^^^ ^ ^ ^  ^ ^ ^
^  ^^^^ ^ ^  ^^ ^ ^
^  ^^^^ ^ ^  ^^ ^  ^
^  ^^^^ ^ ^  ^^  ^^
^  ^^^^ ^ ^  ^^  ^ ^
^  ^^^^ ^ ^  ^ ^^ ^
^  ^^^^ ^ ^  ^ ^^  ^
^  ^^^^ ^ ^  ^ ^ ^^
^  ^^^^ ^ ^  ^ ^ ^ ^
^  ^^^^ ^  ^^ ^ ^ ^
^  ^^^^ ^  ^^ ^ ^  ^
^  ^^^^ ^  ^^ ^  ^^
^  ^^^^ ^  ^^ ^  ^ ^
^  ^^^^ ^  ^^  ^^ ^
^  ^^^^ ^  ^^  ^^  ^
^  ^^^^ ^  ^^  ^ ^^
^  ^^^^ ^  ^^  ^ ^ ^
^  ^^^^ ^  ^ ^^ ^ ^
^  ^^^^ ^  ^ ^^ ^  ^
^  ^^^^ ^  ^ ^^  ^^
^  ^^^^ ^  ^ ^^  ^ ^
^  ^^^^ ^  ^ ^ ^^ ^
^  ^^^^ ^  ^ ^ ^^  ^
^  ^^^^ ^  ^ ^ ^ ^^
^  ^^^^ ^  ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
^  ^^^^  ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^
^  ^^^^  ^^ ^ ^ ^  ^
^  ^^^^  ^^ ^ ^  ^^
^  ^^^^  ^^ ^ ^  ^ ^
^  ^^^^  ^^ ^  ^^ ^
^  ^^^^  ^^ ^  ^^  ^
^  ^^^^  ^^ ^  ^ ^^
^  ^^^^  ^^ ^  ^ ^ ^
^  ^^^^  ^^  ^^ ^ ^
^  ^^^^  ^^  ^^ ^  ^
^  ^^^^  ^^  ^^  ^^
^  ^^^^  ^^  ^^  ^ ^
^  ^^^^  ^^  ^ ^^ ^
^  ^^^^  ^^  ^ ^^  ^
^  ^^^^  ^^  ^ ^ ^^
^  ^^^^  ^^  ^ ^ ^ ^
^  ^^^^  ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^
^  ^^^^  ^ ^^ ^ ^  ^
^  ^^^^  ^ ^^ ^  ^^
^  ^^^^  ^ ^^ ^  ^ ^
^  ^^^^  ^ ^^  ^^ ^
^  ^^^^  ^ ^^  ^^  ^
^  ^^^^  ^ ^^  ^ ^^
^  ^^^^  ^ ^^  ^ ^ ^
^  ^^^^  ^ ^ ^^ ^ ^
^  ^^^^  ^ ^ ^^ ^  ^
^  ^^^^  ^ ^ ^^  ^^
^  ^^^^  ^ ^ ^^  ^ ^
^  ^^^^  ^ ^ ^ ^^ ^
^  ^^^^  ^ ^ ^ ^^  ^
^  ^^^^  ^ ^ ^ ^ ^^
^  ^^^^  ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
^  ^^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
^  ^^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^  ^
^  ^^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^  ^^
^  ^^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^  ^ ^
^  ^^^ ^^ ^ ^  ^^ ^
^  ^^^ ^^ ^ ^  ^^  ^
^  ^^^ ^^ ^ ^  ^ ^^
^  ^^^ ^^ ^ ^  ^ ^ ^
^  ^^^ ^^ ^  ^^ ^ ^
^  ^^^ ^^ ^  ^^ ^  ^
^  ^^^ ^^ ^  ^^  ^^
^  ^^^ ^^ ^  ^^  ^ ^
^  ^^^ ^^ ^  ^ ^^ ^
^  ^^^ ^^ ^  ^ ^^  ^
^  ^^^ ^^ ^  ^ ^ ^^
^  ^^^ ^^ ^  ^ ^ ^ ^
^  ^^^ ^^  ^^ ^ ^ ^
^  ^^^ ^^  ^^ ^ ^  ^
^  ^^^ ^^  ^^ ^  ^^
^  ^^^ ^^  ^^ ^  ^ ^
^  ^^^ ^^  ^^  ^^ ^
^  ^^^ ^^  ^^  ^^  ^
^  ^^^ ^^  ^^  ^ ^^
^  ^^^ ^^  ^^  ^ ^ ^
^  ^^^ ^^  ^ ^^ ^ ^
^  ^^^ ^^  ^ ^^ ^  ^
^  ^^^ ^^  ^ ^^  ^^
^  ^^^ ^^  ^ ^^  ^ ^
^  ^^^ ^^  ^ ^ ^^ ^
^  ^^^ ^^  ^ ^ ^^  ^
^  ^^^ ^^  ^ ^ ^ ^^
^  ^^^ ^^  ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
^  ^^^ ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^
^  ^^^ ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^  ^
^  ^^^ ^ ^^ ^ ^  ^^
^  ^^^ ^ ^^ ^ ^  ^ ^
^  ^^^ ^ ^^ ^  ^^ ^
^  ^^^ ^ ^^ ^  ^^  ^
^  ^^^ ^ ^^ ^  ^ ^^
^  ^^^ ^ ^^ ^  ^ ^ ^
^  ^^^ ^ ^^  ^^ ^ ^
^  ^^^ ^ ^^  ^^ ^  ^
^  ^^^ ^ ^^  ^^  ^^
^  ^^^ ^ ^^  ^^  ^ ^
^  ^^^ ^ ^^  ^ ^^ ^
^  ^^^ ^ ^^  ^ ^^  ^
^  ^^^ ^ ^^  ^ ^ ^^
^  ^^^ ^ ^^  ^ ^ ^ ^
^  ^^^ ^ ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^
^  ^^^ ^ ^ ^^ ^ ^  ^
^  ^^^ ^ ^ ^^ ^  ^^
^  ^^^ ^ ^ ^^ ^  ^ ^
^  ^^^ ^ ^ ^^  ^^ ^
^  ^^^ ^ ^ ^^  ^^  ^
^  ^^^ ^ ^ ^^  ^ ^^
^  ^^^ ^ ^ ^^  ^ ^ ^
^  ^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^^ ^ ^
^  ^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^^ ^  ^
^  ^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^^  ^^
^  ^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^^  ^ ^
^  ^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^^ ^
^  ^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^^  ^
^  ^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^^
^  ^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^  ^
 ^^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^  ^^
 ^^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^  ^ ^
 ^^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^  ^^ ^
 ^^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^  ^^  ^
 ^^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^  ^ ^^
 ^^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^  ^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^^ ^ ^  ^^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^^ ^ ^  ^^ ^  ^
 ^^ ^^^ ^ ^  ^^  ^^
 ^^ ^^^ ^ ^  ^^  ^ ^
 ^^ ^^^ ^ ^  ^ ^^ ^
 ^^ ^^^ ^ ^  ^ ^^  ^
 ^^ ^^^ ^ ^  ^ ^ ^^
 ^^ ^^^ ^ ^  ^ ^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^^ ^  ^^ ^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^^ ^  ^^ ^ ^  ^
 ^^ ^^^ ^  ^^ ^  ^^
 ^^ ^^^ ^  ^^ ^  ^ ^
 ^^ ^^^ ^  ^^  ^^ ^
 ^^ ^^^ ^  ^^  ^^  ^
 ^^ ^^^ ^  ^^  ^ ^^
 ^^ ^^^ ^  ^^  ^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^^ ^  ^ ^^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^^ ^  ^ ^^ ^  ^
 ^^ ^^^ ^  ^ ^^  ^^
 ^^ ^^^ ^  ^ ^^  ^ ^
 ^^ ^^^ ^  ^ ^ ^^ ^
 ^^ ^^^ ^  ^ ^ ^^  ^
 ^^ ^^^ ^  ^ ^ ^ ^^
 ^^ ^^^ ^  ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^^  ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^^  ^^ ^ ^ ^  ^
 ^^ ^^^  ^^ ^ ^  ^^
 ^^ ^^^  ^^ ^ ^  ^ ^
 ^^ ^^^  ^^ ^  ^^ ^
 ^^ ^^^  ^^ ^  ^^  ^
 ^^ ^^^  ^^ ^  ^ ^^
 ^^ ^^^  ^^ ^  ^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^^  ^^  ^^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^^  ^^  ^^ ^  ^
 ^^ ^^^  ^^  ^^  ^^
 ^^ ^^^  ^^  ^^  ^ ^
 ^^ ^^^  ^^  ^ ^^ ^
 ^^ ^^^  ^^  ^ ^^  ^
 ^^ ^^^  ^^  ^ ^ ^^
 ^^ ^^^  ^^  ^ ^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^^  ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^^  ^ ^^ ^ ^  ^
 ^^ ^^^  ^ ^^ ^  ^^
 ^^ ^^^  ^ ^^ ^  ^ ^
 ^^ ^^^  ^ ^^  ^^ ^
 ^^ ^^^  ^ ^^  ^^  ^
 ^^ ^^^  ^ ^^  ^ ^^
 ^^ ^^^  ^ ^^  ^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^^  ^ ^ ^^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^^  ^ ^ ^^ ^  ^
 ^^ ^^^  ^ ^ ^^  ^^
 ^^ ^^^  ^ ^ ^^  ^ ^
 ^^ ^^^  ^ ^ ^ ^^ ^
 ^^ ^^^  ^ ^ ^ ^^  ^
 ^^ ^^^  ^ ^ ^ ^ ^^
 ^^ ^^^  ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^  ^
 ^^ ^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^  ^^
 ^^ ^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^  ^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^^ ^ ^  ^^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^^ ^ ^  ^^  ^
 ^^ ^^ ^^ ^ ^  ^ ^^
 ^^ ^^ ^^ ^ ^  ^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^^ ^  ^^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^^ ^  ^^ ^  ^
 ^^ ^^ ^^ ^  ^^  ^^
 ^^ ^^ ^^ ^  ^^  ^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^^ ^  ^ ^^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^^ ^  ^ ^^  ^
 ^^ ^^ ^^ ^  ^ ^ ^^
 ^^ ^^ ^^ ^  ^ ^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^^  ^^ ^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^^  ^^ ^ ^  ^
 ^^ ^^ ^^  ^^ ^  ^^
 ^^ ^^ ^^  ^^ ^  ^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^^  ^^  ^^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^^  ^^  ^^  ^
 ^^ ^^ ^^  ^^  ^ ^^
 ^^ ^^ ^^  ^^  ^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^^  ^ ^^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^^  ^ ^^ ^  ^
 ^^ ^^ ^^  ^ ^^  ^^
 ^^ ^^ ^^  ^ ^^  ^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^^  ^ ^ ^^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^^  ^ ^ ^^  ^
 ^^ ^^ ^^  ^ ^ ^ ^^
 ^^ ^^ ^^  ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^  ^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^^ ^ ^  ^^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^^ ^ ^  ^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^^ ^  ^^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^^ ^  ^^  ^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^^ ^  ^ ^^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^^ ^  ^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^^  ^^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^^  ^^ ^  ^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^^  ^^  ^^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^^  ^^  ^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^^  ^ ^^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^^  ^ ^^  ^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^^  ^ ^ ^^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^^  ^ ^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^^ ^ ^  ^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^^ ^  ^^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^^ ^  ^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^^  ^^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^^  ^^  ^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^^  ^ ^^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^^  ^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^^ ^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^^ ^  ^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^^  ^^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^^  ^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^^ ^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^^  ^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^^
 ^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^  ^
 ^ ^^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^  ^^
 ^ ^^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^  ^ ^
 ^ ^^^^ ^ ^ ^  ^^ ^
 ^ ^^^^ ^ ^ ^  ^^  ^
 ^ ^^^^ ^ ^ ^  ^ ^^
 ^ ^^^^ ^ ^ ^  ^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^^ ^ ^  ^^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^^ ^ ^  ^^ ^  ^
 ^ ^^^^ ^ ^  ^^  ^^
 ^ ^^^^ ^ ^  ^^  ^ ^
 ^ ^^^^ ^ ^  ^ ^^ ^
 ^ ^^^^ ^ ^  ^ ^^  ^
 ^ ^^^^ ^ ^  ^ ^ ^^
 ^ ^^^^ ^ ^  ^ ^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^^ ^  ^^ ^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^^ ^  ^^ ^ ^  ^
 ^ ^^^^ ^  ^^ ^  ^^
 ^ ^^^^ ^  ^^ ^  ^ ^
 ^ ^^^^ ^  ^^  ^^ ^
 ^ ^^^^ ^  ^^  ^^  ^
 ^ ^^^^ ^  ^^  ^ ^^
 ^ ^^^^ ^  ^^  ^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^^ ^  ^ ^^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^^ ^  ^ ^^ ^  ^
 ^ ^^^^ ^  ^ ^^  ^^
 ^ ^^^^ ^  ^ ^^  ^ ^
 ^ ^^^^ ^  ^ ^ ^^ ^
 ^ ^^^^ ^  ^ ^ ^^  ^
 ^ ^^^^ ^  ^ ^ ^ ^^
 ^ ^^^^ ^  ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^^  ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^^  ^^ ^ ^ ^  ^
 ^ ^^^^  ^^ ^ ^  ^^
 ^ ^^^^  ^^ ^ ^  ^ ^
 ^ ^^^^  ^^ ^  ^^ ^
 ^ ^^^^  ^^ ^  ^^  ^
 ^ ^^^^  ^^ ^  ^ ^^
 ^ ^^^^  ^^ ^  ^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^^  ^^  ^^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^^  ^^  ^^ ^  ^
 ^ ^^^^  ^^  ^^  ^^
 ^ ^^^^  ^^  ^^  ^ ^
 ^ ^^^^  ^^  ^ ^^ ^
 ^ ^^^^  ^^  ^ ^^  ^
 ^ ^^^^  ^^  ^ ^ ^^
 ^ ^^^^  ^^  ^ ^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^^  ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^^  ^ ^^ ^ ^  ^
 ^ ^^^^  ^ ^^ ^  ^^
 ^ ^^^^  ^ ^^ ^  ^ ^
 ^ ^^^^  ^ ^^  ^^ ^
 ^ ^^^^  ^ ^^  ^^  ^
 ^ ^^^^  ^ ^^  ^ ^^
 ^ ^^^^  ^ ^^  ^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^^  ^ ^ ^^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^^  ^ ^ ^^ ^  ^
 ^ ^^^^  ^ ^ ^^  ^^
 ^ ^^^^  ^ ^ ^^  ^ ^
 ^ ^^^^  ^ ^ ^ ^^ ^
 ^ ^^^^  ^ ^ ^ ^^  ^
 ^ ^^^^  ^ ^ ^ ^ ^^
 ^ ^^^^  ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^  ^
 ^ ^^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^  ^^
 ^ ^^^ ^^ ^ ^ ^  ^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^^ ^ ^  ^^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^^ ^ ^  ^^  ^
 ^ ^^^ ^^ ^ ^  ^ ^^
 ^ ^^^ ^^ ^ ^  ^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^^ ^  ^^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^^ ^  ^^ ^  ^
 ^ ^^^ ^^ ^  ^^  ^^
 ^ ^^^ ^^ ^  ^^  ^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^^ ^  ^ ^^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^^ ^  ^ ^^  ^
 ^ ^^^ ^^ ^  ^ ^ ^^
 ^ ^^^ ^^ ^  ^ ^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^^  ^^ ^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^^  ^^ ^ ^  ^
 ^ ^^^ ^^  ^^ ^  ^^
 ^ ^^^ ^^  ^^ ^  ^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^^  ^^  ^^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^^  ^^  ^^  ^
 ^ ^^^ ^^  ^^  ^ ^^
 ^ ^^^ ^^  ^^  ^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^^  ^ ^^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^^  ^ ^^ ^  ^
 ^ ^^^ ^^  ^ ^^  ^^
 ^ ^^^ ^^  ^ ^^  ^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^^  ^ ^ ^^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^^  ^ ^ ^^  ^
 ^ ^^^ ^^  ^ ^ ^ ^^
 ^ ^^^ ^^  ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^  ^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^^ ^ ^  ^^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^^ ^ ^  ^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^^ ^  ^^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^^ ^  ^^  ^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^^ ^  ^ ^^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^^ ^  ^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^^  ^^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^^  ^^ ^  ^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^^  ^^  ^^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^^  ^^  ^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^^  ^ ^^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^^  ^ ^^  ^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^^  ^ ^ ^^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^^  ^ ^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^^ ^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^^ ^ ^  ^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^^ ^  ^^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^^ ^  ^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^^  ^^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^^  ^^  ^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^^  ^ ^^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^^  ^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^^ ^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^^ ^  ^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^^  ^^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^^  ^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^^ ^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^^  ^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^^
 ^ ^^^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can't find more than only one result because of two reasons

- You only search for one character (`h` instead of `h*`).
- You don't have any matching groups at all

You can use this site as a testzone for regex: https://regex101.com/r/uT8eS0/1

First of all you have to define matching groups if you want to have more than only one match. Otherwise you will only get one match all the time. Also you are searching for a single character as you are searching for `h`. If you want to match multiple you have to change this to `h*` or `h+`. If you decide for `+` it matches one to unlimited characters. If you take `*` it will match zero to unlimited characters.

Changing you pattern to `"h+.*e+.*l+.*l+.*o+.* .*w+.*o+.*r+.*l+.*d+` will also match the chars between as they are handled in the `.*` directive between your chars in the pattern you posted. Afaik it's not possible to match different groups in only one string. You could seperate each char in a group or subgroup but this will result in a high amount of different groups.

Answer (score 0):

I know, I should have written this in C#, but I dashed it out in PERL, cause it knows regex too; and it was easier @ the time.

```
$_ = "hheelllloo";

sub matchmaker {
  my @blah = @_;
  if ($blah[0] =~ /[h]{$blah[1],}[e]{$blah[1],}[l]{$blah[1],}[l]{$blah[1],}[o]{$blah[1],}/) {
    $blah[1]++;
    print("deeper\n");
    matchmaker($blah[0],$blah[1]);
   } else {
     return $blah[1]-1;
  }
}

$match = matchmaker($_,1);
print("match ",$match);
```

It is recursive function if you will that looks at your string and asks for increasingly more and more of letters matching the pattern you asked for. You could convert this to c# in 5 minutes. The key the regex syntax that says pattern{min,max}; you increase the min and leave the max to be as greedy as it can. So I look for one h, followed by one e, then one l, than another l than an o. If I find all, I look for 2 h, 2 e, 2 l, 2 more l and 2 o... you get the idea.

Now if you want to enhance this function, and get even more matches, you move one letter forward in your string and rerun your match.

You can play with this for a while, is it efficient. No idea :)

Comment: What does Swift have to do with the question? Or Perl for that matter? OP asks for a C# solution.

Comment: Yes, your right I didn't read it correctly. Changed it Lucas.

Comment: I'm still struggling to identify which language are you talking about: C#, C++, Perl, Swift...

Comment: It is C#, its in the comments I see it now.

Comment: what's the time complexity of this approach?

Comment: Sorry, don't know the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59894545/2582581) solution for a similar problem (It's in javascript but it's easy to understand).